# jQuery if table has more than 2 td in a row with 2 conditions

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to combine 2 conditions in an "if" statement if possible.

I want to first check the screen width and then see if there are more than 2 td's in a row or first row of a table. If there is do some function.

This is what I have as my first part for the width but how would I add in the other condition that needs to be met?

```
var width = parseInt($(window).width());
if (width<=610) {  
//Need to add the other condition that is a table has more than 2 td's in a row

}
```

Here is the real code I am trying to run. See my comment for executing if more than 2 columns.

```
var width = parseInt($(window).width());
if (width<=610) {   

    //Need to figure out how execute this if there are more than 2 columns in the table???
    $('.content table').replaceWith(function() {

    var $th = $(this).find('th'); // get headers
    var th = $th.map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get(); // and their values

    $th.closest('tr').remove(); // then remove them

    var $d = $('<div>', { 'class': 'responsive-table' });

    $('tr', this).each(function(i, el) {
        var $div = $('<div>', {'class': 'box grey-bg'}).appendTo($d);
        $('td', this).each(function(j, el) {
            var n = j + 1;
            var $row = $('<div>', {
                //'class': 'row-' + n
                'class': 'row'
            });
            $row.append(
            $('<span>', {
                //'class': 'label-' + n,
                'class': 'label',
                text: th[j]
            }), ' : ', $('<span>', {
                //'class': 'data-' + n,
                'class': 'data',
                text: $(this).text()
            })).appendTo($div);
        });
    });
    return $d;  
    }); 

};
```

Comment: jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/umDNC/

Comment: updated example http://jsfiddle.net/umDNC/1/

Comment: Latest test but no luck http://jsfiddle.net/umDNC/15/ :(

Comment: Successful tests were done, see my new answer which is not locked yet by Stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try below, assuming that you just want to get the col count of a table..

```
var width = parseInt($(window).width());
var tableColCount = $('#tableID tr:first').find('td').length;

if (width<=610 && tableColCount  > 2) {  
  //Your code

}
```

Comment: sorry i updated my code with the real code i am trying to modify. Should have posted it in the beginning. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: @Aaron Did your issue got resolved or do you need some help? Did Lajos Arpad answer worked for you?

Comment: No i am still struggling to figure out how to get the length part to work with my updated code above and and have it work for every table in the div "content" and this part $('.content table').replaceWith(function() {

Comment: you think you can take a look at this and tell me what i am doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkResult() {
    $("#IDOfYourTable tr").each(function() {
        if ((($this).find("td").size() > 1) || (($this).find("th").size() > 1))
            return true;
    });
    return false;
}
```

Use this function in your if clause.

Corrected code:

```
var width = parseInt($(window).width());
var that = undefined;
function checkResult() {
    if (width <= 610) {
        $(".content table tr").each(function() {
            if (($(this).find("td").size() > 2) || ($(this).find("th").size() > 2))
            {
                if ((that == undefined) || (that[0] != this)) {
                that = $(this);
    var $th = $(this).find('th'); // get headers
    var th = $th.map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get(); // and their values

    $th.closest('tr').remove(); // then remove them

    var $d = $('<div>', { 'class': 'responsive-table' });

    $('tr', this).each(function(i, el) {
        var $div = $('<div>', {'class': 'box grey-bg'}).appendTo($d);
        $('td', this).each(function(j, el) {
            var n = j + 1;
            var $row = $('<div>', {
                //'class': 'row-' + n
                'class': 'row'
            });
            $row.append(
            $('<span>', {
                //'class': 'label-' + n,
                'class': 'label',
                text: th[j]
            }), ' : ', $('<span>', {
                //'class': 'data-' + n,
                'class': 'data',
                text: $(this).text()
            })).appendTo($div);
        });
    });
            }
        }
                                    });
    }
}
checkResult();                                    





​
```

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a live interactive debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Need to figure out how execute this if there are more than 2 columns in the table???
function foo(that) {
    that.find("tr").each(function(){
        if ($(this).find("td").size() > 2)
            that.addClass("strip-these");  
            return;
    });
}

$('.content table').each(function() {
    foo($(this));
});
console.log($(".strip-these"));
$('.strip-these').each(function() {
    $('tr', this).each(function() {
        var length = $('td', this).length;
        console.log(length);
        if (length > 2) {
            // code
            $('.strip-these').replaceWith(function() {

                var $th = $(this).find('th'); // get headers
                var th = $th.map(function() {
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get(); // and their values
                $th.closest('tr').remove(); // then remove them
                var $d = $('<div>', {
                    'class': 'responsive-table'
                });

                $('tr', this).each(function(i, el) {
                    var $div = $('<div>', {
                        'class': 'box grey-bg'
                    }).appendTo($d);
                    $('td', this).each(function(j, el) {
                        var n = j + 1;
                        var $row = $('<div>', {
                            //'class': 'row-' + n
                            'class': 'row'
                        });
                        $row.append(
                        $('<span>', {
                            //'class': 'label-' + n,
                            'class': 'label',
                            text: th[j]
                        }), ' : ', $('<span>', {
                            //'class': 'data-' + n,
                            'class': 'data',
                            text: $(this).text()
                        })).appendTo($div);
                    });
                });
                return $d;
            });



        }
    });
});​
```